# How to get the string from Content.ReadAsStringAsync method in .Net Core?

Tags: c#, .net, asp.net-core-webapi, webapi

I am trying to read the response from WebAPI, that returns string.
I use below statement:

```
response.Content.ReadAsStringAsync().Result.ToString();
```

I was expecting the result to be `"TEST"` but I am getting `"\"TEST\""`.

How do I remove the extra characters from the output.

I ran the API alone in Postman, and getting expected result `"TEST"`. But when I try to read the response via code, I am getting extra characters.

Not sure, where I am missing. Any help on this really appreciated.

Edit: Adding screenshot of the response:

[image: screenshot]

Comment: Is double quote a part of the response?

Comment: Actually the response is "\"TEST\""

Comment: That string was probably sent as json, that's why those extra quotes are there

Comment: And there are no backslashes in the value. That is just the debugger displaying it in a code-ready way

Comment: backslashes is coming with the response when I call WEB API from the code. Now how to remove that backslashes from the response?

Comment: Were you expecting the result to be `TEST` or `"TEST"`? The debugger represents the string the way you would write it in C#, so `"TEST"` would appear as `"\"TEST\""`. Postman doesn't do this, so if Postman shows the result as `"TEST"`, that means there are quotes around `TEST` in the response.

Comment: Found the response is sending double quotes, the backslashes are are escape character for that double codes. With the help of replace string, I was able to remove the double quotes

Answer (score 3):

The correct way would be to use `await` to read the string result:

```
var result = await response.Content.ReadAsStringAsync();
```

And you would not need to use `.ToString()` because the result is already a string.

To manually remove the double quotes from the output you can just trim it:

```
result = result.Trim('"');
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply, but still I am getting additional characters in the output. "\"TEST\""

Comment: @Keerthi well, I've updated the answer, I'm just not really sure if your output should contain those double quotes or not.

Comment: If the response is not supposed to be sending those extra quotes, go to the code where the response is being sent and fix the issue there: most likely it's returning a response to be encoded as JSON rather than a simple string. If you can't change it, you're probably better off JSON-decoding the string. With just a Trim, any `\"`s in the string won't be decoded correctly, for example.